# MySQL Connector/Python .dmg installation on osx "succeeds" but I cannot find the module

Tags: python, mysql, macos, connector, dmg

I downloaded Mysql Connector/Python 1.1.6  .DMG for OSX    http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

When I run it, it says "installation successful" but gives no other installation or diagnostics.

But when I try to verify the successful installation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-verification.html

it says cannot find the module

```
vt102:~ xxxxx$ python

Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.2 (x86_64)| (default, Jan 10 2014, 11:23:15) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import mysql.connector

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

Everything has been working easily w/ python so far, but this mysql/python stuff has been a nightmare.  Any advice?

//UPDATE

I found the install.log  and searched for clues from the installation, but i don't see anything useful or suspicious

```
Apr 24 08:45:02 vt102.local Installer[8474]: MySQL database driver written in pure Python  Installation Log
Apr 24 08:45:02 vt102.local Installer[8474]: Opened from: /Volumes/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg
Apr 24 08:45:02 vt102.local Installer[8474]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://mysql-connector-python-1.1.6/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg
Apr 24 08:45:02 vt102.local Installer[8474]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg
Apr 24 08:45:46 vt102.local Installer[8474]:    Upgrade: "MySQL database driver written in pure Python"
Apr 24 08:45:46 vt102.local Installer[8474]:        mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg : com.oracle.mysql.connector.python : 1.1.6.1.1
Apr 24 08:45:46 vt102.local Installer[8474]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg>"
Apr 24 08:45:46 vt102.local installd[413]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.oracle.mysql.connector.python (prefix path=)
Apr 24 08:45:46 vt102.local installd[413]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/0992398D-F177-487C-8A6F-7A43E760ED1B.activeSandbox/Root, uid=0)
Apr 24 08:45:47 vt102.local installd[413]: PackageKit: Writing receipt for com.oracle.mysql.connector.python to /private/var/db/receipts
Apr 24 08:45:47 vt102.local installd[413]: Installed "MySQL database driver written in pure Python" ()
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle doesn't let you choose the install path; here's a work around:

1. Download the [platform independent version](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) from Oracle.
2. Unzip the folder and place it within the `anaconda` directory.
3. Open the terminal and navigate into the directory of the mysql connector.
4. Type: `python setup.py install`